# Angular 2+ store and access dynamic image library

Tags: image, angular, build, assets

I am using Angular-cli for this build and it compiles all folders under the src folder into the build.
I was storing images in the assets folder under src:

`src
|-app
|-assets
   |-img_library`

I access them dynamically like this:
 `<img src="assets/img_library/{{imgId}}"`

Unfortunately this folder gets compiled into the build by angular-cli, so I would have to rebuild the app every time an image is added for the client to be able to access it.

I built the server as well so I can store the images anywhere I want but I don't know how to access folders above the `src` via a `img` tag.

Is there a way to access a public/assets folder above the `src` folder with an image tag in Angular?

Comment: That doesn't make sense - if you access an assets folder outside `src/`, you *still* have to include it and rebuild when you add images. Instead, split the app up - have a simple API or something that returns a list of links and then they can live *anywhere* (same server, another server, S3, CDN, ...).

Comment: If there is a way to access a folder stored above my src folder I wouldn't have to rebuild because it wouldn't be compiled into the build. Building api to access images via an image tag, seems like using a bulldozer to knock over an ant hill. That's why in traditional web development you would have a public folder to hold these assets.

Comment: It not being compiled into the build is a *problem*, not a solution. How do you make sure it's in the right place when you deploy? And how does the app discover images?

Comment: The same way I would if I access it via an api, by understanding the folder structure and requesting an image at a specified path. Again, I am simply asking if there is a way for an image tag used in Angular to access a folder that is a sibling of the src folder. If there isn't I'll start writing an http.get request to pull the image I need. This seems like it would be a common requirement. Many apps need to solve for storing user media.

Answer (score 1):

@jonrsharpe You're right this doesn't make any sense. The assets folder is for images/media that will be used often by most users. I don't know what I was thinking, my brain was stuck in Angular mode when I needed to approach it from the backend.

I used an express api:

```
router.get('/some/api/:id/img.png', function( req, res, next){

    var id = req.params.id,
        filePath = 'img.png',
        root = __dirname + '/some/location/' + id +'/';

    var options = {
        root: root,
        dotfiles: 'deny',
        headers: {
            'x-timestamp': Date.now(),
            'x-sent': true
        }
    };

    res.sendFile(filePath, options, (err) => {
        if (err) {
            next(err);
        } else {
            console.log('Sent:', filePath);
        }
    });
})
```

to respond to a get request from `<img src='some/api/{{imageId}}/img.png'>`.

Hope this helps some other sleep deprived developer.